# Adding 30 days on the value from JDateChooser using Java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

hi all I am working on a form using `JDateChooser` I want to get the value of date inputted by the user. Is there any ways that after storing the value of date in a variable can I add *30* days from the inputted date? This is my code in passing the date to a string variable:

```
String dates =((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
```

my problem is how can I pass the date into a variable where i can be able to add an additional *30* days on it?
please help me really need this for my project .

Comment: how about referring to this video tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1-ttUrRhl0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate a `String` with a date value, you first need to convert to a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), then you can perform manipulation using a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat datefmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // Or format you're using
Date date = datefmt.parse(dates);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30); // Add 30 days
Date futureDate = cal.getTime();
```

If you need value for insertion into a database, you will of course use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), so you'll need a [`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead:

```
// From Date
Timestamp futureTimestamp = new Timestamp(futureDate.getTime());

// Directly from Calendar
Timestamp futureTimestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: do I need to sorround it w/ try and catch statement? when I type the Date today = datefmt.parse(dates); it gives me an error and gives me a suggestion to sourround it w/ try and catch?

Comment: That or add to the `throws` of your method. Up to you how you want to handle a bad date value. If string should never be bad at this point (enforced earlier, somehow), you should do the `try-catch` and rethrow as `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: dates =((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            SimpleDateFormat datefmt =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date today = datefmt.parse(dates);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(today);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30); // Add 30 days
            Date futureDate = cal.getTime();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, futureDate);

Comment: that codes work fine now and now my problem is it also give me a time which is not set, how am I abe to set it? please help me realy need it  so bad..

Comment: @pinkywest That sounds like a different question, so I suggest you ask a new question, providing the relevant information.